# Group A twice as big as Group B, but no significant difference?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, mean

I want to compare the means between two measurement methods, but the readings are non-normally distributed. Despite almost every "Y" measurement being more than twice the corresponding "X" measurement, my T-Tests aren't showing any statistically significant difference.

Fair warning I am not a statistician by any means.

This example shows my issue:

```
individual <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
measure <- c("X","X","X","X","X","X", "Y","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y")
value <- c("350", "15", "7", "2", "1", "1","800", "60", "20", "5", "3", "1")


df <- data.frame(individual, measure, value)
df$measure <- as.factor(df$measure)
df$value <- as.numeric(df$value)
 

TT <- t.test(df$value~df$measure)
TT
```

Gives the following output:

```
        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  df$value by df$measure
t = -0.59885, df = 6.8666, p-value = 0.5685
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -424.4406  253.4406
sample estimates:
mean in group X mean in group Y 
       62.66667       148.16667
```

I also tried an ANOVA, to account for the individual:

```
res.aov2 <- aov(value ~ measure + individual, data = df)
summary(res.aov2)
```

and get:

```
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
measure      1  21931   21931   1.363 0.2956  
individual   5 531109  106222   6.604 0.0294 *
Residuals    5  80423   16085                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I've also tried a Wilcoxon Signed- Rank

```
wilcox.test(df$grp1, df$grp2, paired = TRUE)
```

and got:

```
    Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  df$grp1 and df$grp2
V = 15, p-value = 0.05906
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(df$grp1, df$grp2, paired = TRUE) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

I'm not really sure what else I can do. I would accept that they're not significant, but surely there's something in the fact that they're twice the size?

Comment: It's a tall order to judge the applicability of a parametric test from 6 pairs of observations. Another non-parametric option is a permutation test.

Comment: Furthermore, you say that X and Y are two measurement methods. Looking at the mean of (X - Y) doesn't look like a particularly compelling thing to do. Isn't it more relevant to consider how accurate (if at all) either measurement is for the range of possible values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are talking about corresponding $X$ and $Y$ measurements, you should probably use a paired test. However, with the `t.test`, you used the non-paired version. Furthermore, the `t.test` presumes normally distributed measurements and your measurements don't look very normal.

Now, if you have paired data that is not necessarily normally distributed, the `wilcox.test` would be appropriate, provided we have independent pairs.

And, as you can see, the p-value of `wilcox.test` is very near 0.05, a common significance level. Note, that the last pair $X=1, Y=1$ cannot be used since this is a draw. That is what the warning in the `wilcox.test` output is about.

Finally, considering that you have only a small amount of data and their values are very far spread out, I would not expect a very significant result.

Comment: Thanks! I ending up running the wilcox.test on my actual dataset, which is much larger, and the result ended up being p<0.01

Comment: Here as elsewhere it remains puzzling if not irritating that whoever named `wilcox.test` felt that saving two characters was a bigger deal than honouring Wilcoxon.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree mildly with the advice to jump straight to Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney as too pessimistic.

The substantive information that might inform an analysis that makes sense scientifically as well as statistically has been removed by the bland names `measure` and `value`, but the data example suggests working on logarithmic scale.

Here is a supportive graph of the ordered data on logarithmic scale (a quantile plot, or if you prefer an empirical cumulative distribution plot with axes reversed).

[image]

I would be happy to pursue a $t$ test on such a scale, or perhaps even better to use a generalized linear model with logarithmic link.

However, if zero is a possible value, you may need something different, but the idea of working on a transformed scale still seems a serious competitor. GLM with logarithmic link presumes only that means are positive, not that all values are.

Comment: I would suggest that this plot would be more informative if you connect the two points by the same subject with a line segment.

Comment: I am fine with that. I just wanted to emphasise that the transformed distributions are fair for a a t test. Doubting that is what seems to be driving the pessimistic advice to use Wilcoxon.

Comment: To me at least, any advice can end up being irrelevant to the full dataset which is "much larger" than 6. Anything can be true for the actual data. And with the parameteric test there is the chance that the OP will end up in the situation discussed by @Glen_b [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/591580/anova-vs-kruskal-wallis). So the non-parametric test is perhaps better described as realistic rather than pessimistic, as we know very little.

Comment: I'd  use the same argument to reach the opposite conclusions. The full dataset is what it matters, not the tiny subset -- I agree there -- but similarly it contains as much information as is available to decide what scale to work on. The idea that people care about comparing measurements but need to analyse their ranks instead is, I submit, not just pessimistic but doesn't match the way scientists would prefer to work.

Comment: I agree about the ranks of the measurements. But I'm not sure a t-test, even under the best of conditions, tells something especially interesting about comparative accuracy or calibration of two measuring instruments. (I think my point is that the OP told us not much, so the answers cannot tell her that much.)

Comment: The OP wants to compare two different measurement methods. I agree that the difference in means is just one aspect and not necessarily central. I have entire papers agreeing with you there: https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0005  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169555X05003740